# If statements with multi conditions

Tags: c++, if-statement

I am trying to form an if statement like so:

```
int myVariable = -1;
if (0 <= myVariable <= 99)
{
   // Do something
}
```

However, if I assigned `-1` to `myVariable`, which is an `int`, the if-statement still evaluations to **true**.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is not the correct way to say what you want in C++ syntax. You want:

```
int myVariable = -1;
if (0 <= myVariable && myVariable <= 99)
{
   // Do something
}
```

What you wrote does the following:
1) Evaluate `0 <= myVariable`, which in your example will be false (converted to 0 in C++ in this context)
2) Then this result (0) is compared against <= 99, so C++ reads "0 <= 99", which is true, so the if statement is true.

Comment: Technically false is represented by 0 in C. In C++ `false` is it's own value which can be implicitly converted to an int, and when that happens the value of the int is 0. I think most C++ compilers should have a warning you can enable to flag such implicit conversions of bool to int.

Comment: Technically, it *is* C++ syntax (or else it wouldn't compile).  It's just not the logic that most people intend when they write it. :P